# How to access a variable through multiple commands with discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a game with my discord bot but for each @client.command I need to be using the same variable, if anyone knows how I can do this that would be helpful!

Comment: What about global variables?

Comment: You can also try `bot.my_var = "hello"` (this can be accessed everywhere you have access to your bot instance)